# How to sort using ase.build.sort?

Tags: software-assistance, atomic-simulation-environment

I am trying to sort a set of Cu atoms in a fcc (non primitive) crystal structure according to their Z cordinate. I am using `ase.build.sort` to do this with the help of doccumentation. The doccumentation says that for `ase.build.sort(atoms, tags=None)`, it will return a new `Atoms` object with sorted atomic order. The default is to order according to chemical symbols, but if tags is not `None`, it will be used instead.

But there is no clue given how to sort in some different manner (not according to chemical symbols).

Here is my code:

```
import os
import numpy
import ase
import ase.io
import ase.build
import ase.visualize

from ase.build import bulk
from ase.build.tools import sort

Cu=ase.build.bulk('Cu','fcc',a=3.6, cubic=True)
surface=ase.build.surface(Cu,(1,1,1),4,vacuum=15)

from ase.build import bulk
from ase.build.tools import sort

surface_sorted = sort(surface,tag=)
```

What should I put in the tag so that I can get it sorted according to z coordinates?

Answer (score 8):

The following code should create a Cu surface and sort it by z index.  We do this by providing tags for the positions of the atoms.  `[:, 2]` allows us to select the z position of all atoms.

```
from ase.build import bulk, surface
from ase.build.tools import sort

Cu = ase.build.bulk('Cu', 'fcc', a=3.6, cubic=True)
surface = ase.build.surface(Cu, (1,1,1), 4, vacuum=15)

surface_sorted = sort(surface, tags=surface.positions[:, 2])
```